# Instantiating a model with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, instantiation

I have a question regarding instantiating a model with a belongs_to association.

Taken from the start of http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html :

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

This instantiation works:

```
@order = @customer.orders.create(:order_date => Time.now)
```

But would this work just as well?

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :customer
  belongs_to :customer
end

@customer = Customer.new
@order = Order.create(:customer => @customer)
```

My experiments indicate that it does, to some extent.. But since associations are loaded lazily, it might be tricky in some cases (I can give one example, if you'd like).

So my question is: 
To what extent does that instantiation work just as well as the former?

Comment: or even with this instantiation: @order = Order.create(:customer_id => @customer.id) Which I presume is similar to the latter stated above.

Answer (score 1):

These two forms both work.

Either way you have an Order object with a customer_id field set to the ID of an existing customer.  When you call customer.orders.create() it's populating that association behind the scenes.  In your second example you are doing it manually.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Why is the attr_accessible :customer erroneous? Isn't it required to be able to input :customer into the constructor?

Comment: I'm wrong, attr_accessible is exactly what you want to declare that attribute as the white-list for the attributes hash.  Edited my answer to remove that comment.  I misread attr_accessible() for attr_accessor(), which would be superfluous.